# Download videos then play the local copy in Android Webview

Tags: android, video, webview, local

I'm building a thin native wrapper for a web application on Android. I want to keep my HTML & Javascript on the web, as it'll reduce the frequency with which the App needs to be updated.

However, I want to take advantage of SD card storage for storing videos -- my application has several videos that are likely to be played multiple times, so I'd rather download them and play them from the local copy.

What I have already done successfully:

- Written a `@JavascriptInterface` that gets called when the page is being viewed through the app that downloads the videos and saves them to `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).getAbsolutePath()`
- Written a script that replaces the `src` of the html element with a `file://` Url once the download is complete.

**The Problem**

I'm getting a javascript error in the console:

`"Not allowed to load local resource: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/path/to/video.mp4"`

I presume this is because I have a video element

`<video src="file:///......."/>`

Which is being served by a different (non local) domain, so webview's security is saying no.

There are several `WebSettings` methods like `setAllowFileAccess()`, but they specifically state this  only enables JavaScript access to files and not HTML elements such as `<img>` or (in this case) `<video>`

Is there any way around this?
If not, what should my alternative approach be?

**EDIT**:

Could I just use the built in browser cache for this?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a basic content provider? `content://` URIs should work fine.

Comment: I haven't, I thought this might be an approach. I will look into it now. To be honest I've never used them before and they look complex so I was hoping to avoid it!

Comment: They're really super-easy once you get the hang of it. commonsware has a great sample on github: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files

Comment: Didn't work, now I get: `"Not allowed to load local resource: content://path/to/video/test3.mp4"`

Comment: Looks like it's a [bug in 4.4](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63033)

Comment: Yikes, good find though. The hackish way around this would be to load the content with an passthrough, this is, to map `content://server/....` to `http://server.com/....`. Might not be too hackish, as Google will probably respond with a cross-domain scripting concern.